# Are chained thread safe collections thread safe?

Tags: java, collections, thread-safety

If I have the following declaration:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Person>> families = 
   Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<String, Map<String, Person>>());
```

If I then chain a call like so:

```
families.get(lastName).put(firstName, new Person());
```

Is this thread safe?  To me it looks like only one of the two maps is synchronized but you cannot get to the inner map without going through the outer synchronized map so I am unsure...

EDIT
Excellent points made in both answers so far thanks a bunch!  But now I am thinking what if I did this:

```
families.put(lastName, Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<String, Person>());
```

**then** did my chained call, is that entire chain thread safe?  Is it possible that between the `get(lastName)` and `put(firstName, new Person())` that another thread could get the inner map?  I am thinking that if I want the entire chain thread safe I need to put it inside of a synchronized block, but I am also wondering if this will work as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perfectly possible that between calls to the outer get() and to the inner put() some other thread calls the outer get() too and gets the same inner map. But since it is synchronized, it should be safe anyway.

The problem is when you put something into the outer map. How does a thread determine if it is necessary to create a new inner map? Suppose you have a code like this:

```
if (!families.containsKey(lastName)) {
  families.put(lastName, Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<String, Person>());
}
```

Now, this is definitely unsafe as some other thread may do the same thing at the same time, so you end up creating two inner maps one of which becomes a candidate for garbage collecting right away.

It's much better to just synchronize all methods that work with the whole structure, and don't use synchronized maps. It will probably be faster too as you only need one level of synchronization.

Answer (score 4):

You'll get the inner map through the synchronised outer map, but then you can do what you want with it. So that's *not* thread safe.

If you really want thread safety in this scenario, I'd create an object that contains the map of maps, and then you can control access via synchronising the accessors. I suggest this is a good practise for most scenarios where you compose collections of collections.

Answer (score 4):

The inner map is *not* thread-safe.

If some other thread does

```
families.get(lastName).put(firstName, new Person());
```

with the *same* `lastName`, then it's possible for one thread to get the inner map, then the other thread gets the inner map, then both call `put` at the same time and break everything.

Using `synchronizedMap` is often not sufficient for correct concurrency - usually you want to explicitly lock around each *transaction*, rather than around each *method call*.